# Django : array within a query string as foo[]=bar1&foo[]=bar2

Tags: arrays, django, querystringparameter

I need to prepare a Django microservice that offer the following url pattern :

```
http://<myserver>/getinfo/?foo[]=bar1&foo[]=bar2
```

it seems to be a very PHP way of doing but i have to mimic it in django ...

Is there a standard way in Django for both designing the URL and retrieving the querystring parameter as a list in the View ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrt/ "designing the url", Django's urlpatterns ignore the querystring (they only match on the path), so you don't have anything to do here.

wrt/ retrieving the querystring params as a list, that's already handled by [Django's `QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

> QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)
>
> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and a default value wasn’t provided. It’s guaranteed to return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.

NB: forgot to add that Django will not automagically remove the brackets from the key so you'll need `foos = request.GET.getlist("foo[]")` (thanks Daniel Roseman)

Comment: Worth noting also that Django will just treat the `[]` as part of the key, so you would need to do `request.GET.getlist('foo[]')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the precision, I indeed forgot to mention this...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers How would you configure `urls.py` to accept `[]` in urls?

Comment: Let's say I have `getinfo/?foo[]=bar1&foo[]=bar2&poo[]=pie1&poo[]=pie2`